# MySQL UPDATE and SELECT in one pass

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I have a MySQL table of tasks to perform, each row having parameters for a single task.
There are many worker apps (possibly on different machines), performing tasks in a loop.
The apps access the database using MySQL's native C APIs.

In order to own a task, an app does something like that:

- Generate a globally-unique id (for simplicity, let's say it is a number)
- `UPDATE tasks`
  `SET guid = %d`
  `WHERE guid = 0 LIMIT 1`
- `SELECT params`
  `FROM tasks`
  `WHERE guid = %d`
- If the last query returns a row, we own it and have the parameters to run

Is there a way to achieve the same effect (i.e. 'own' a row and get its parameters) in a single call to the server?

Answer (score 10):

try like this

```
UPDATE `lastid` SET `idnum` =  (SELECT `id` FROM `history` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 1);
```

above code worked for me

Comment: Worked for me too. I prefer this method.

Comment: Is this race condition safe

Answer (score 7):

You may create a procedure that does it:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE prc_get_task (in_guid BINARY(16), OUT out_params VARCHAR(200))
BEGIN

  DECLARE task_id INT;

  SELECT id, out_params
  INTO task_id, out_params
  FROM tasks
  WHERE guid = 0
  LIMIT 1
  FOR UPDATE;

  UPDATE task
  SET guid = in_guid
  WHERE id = task_id;

END;

BEGIN TRANSACTION;

CALL prc_get_task(@guid, @params);

COMMIT;
```

Comment: Tried something similar. Bottom line: native SQL queries are much much faster than stored procedures.

Comment: In MySQL there is not so much difference as, say, in Oracle. You can't do it in a single query anyway, but the procedure is one call to the server, just as you asked. With a little effort you can event put BEGIN and COMMIT into the procedure, but it's better be done from application, just in case.

Comment: So basically you are saying that it is not doable in a single call. I was hoping some form of INSERT INTO _tmp SELECT .. would be king enough to allow a mysql_store_results() call as it does allows mysql_affected_rows()

Comment: Calling a procedure IS a single call to the server, if that's what you mean. Calling mysql_store_result() after an INSERT has been long waited for but it's still unimplemented for now, AFAIK.

Comment: i guess for update will take lock on all rows meeting the where clause criteria it will not be limited 1 row

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking for a single query then it can't happen.  The UPDATE function specifically returns just the number of items that were updated.  Similarly, the SELECT function doesn't alter a table, only return values.

Using a procedure will indeed turn it into a single function and it can be handy if locking is a concern for you. If your biggest concern is network traffic (ie: passing too many queries) then use the procedure. If you concern is server overload (ie: the DB is working too hard) then the extra overhead of a procedure could make things worse.

Comment: The concern is indeed the server overload. My hope was that since the update already 'seek()ed' to the row, a SELECT would be easier for the server within the same statement.

Comment: I am also looking for a single SELECT/UPDATE and found this question. I don't want it for locking though, but to modify the LastAccessed column in the row to NOW() when the row is retrieved

Comment: Hi Paulo, can you explain (or give a link) why procedures would make things slower for DB? I thought that SP are quicker :S

Answer (score 1):

I have the exact same issue. We ended up using PostreSQL instead, and [`UPDATE ... RETURNING`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-update.html):

> The optional RETURNING clause causes UPDATE to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually updated. Any expression using the table's columns, and/or columns of other tables mentioned in FROM, can be computed. The new (post-update) values of the table's columns are used. The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the output list of SELECT.

Example: `UPDATE 'my_table' SET 'status' = 1 WHERE 'status' = 0 LIMIT 1 RETURNING *;`

Or, in your case: `UPDATE 'tasks' SET 'guid' = %d WHERE 'guid' = 0 LIMIT 1 RETURNING 'params';`

Sorry, I know this doesn't answer the question with MySQL, and it might not be easy to just switch to PostgreSQL, but it's the best way we've found to do it. Even 6 years later, MySQL still doesn't support `UPDATE ... RETURNING`. It might be added at some point in the future, but for now [MariaDB only has it for DELETE statements](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/delete/).

***Edit***: There is a task (low priority) to [add `UPDATE ... RETURNING` support to MariaDB](https://mariadb.atlassian.net/browse/MDEV-5092).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about the single call part, but what you're describing is a lock.  Locks are an essential element of relational databases.

I don't know the specifics of locking a row, reading it, and then updating it in MySQL, but with a bit of reading of the [mysql lock documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/lock-tables.html) you could do all kinds of lock-based manipulations.

The postgres documenation of [locks](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.1/static/sql-lock.html) has a great example describing exactly what you want to do: lock the table, read the table, modify the table.

Comment: Locks are an overkill in this case. The solution above uses MySQL internal locking, thus is much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE tasks
SET guid = %d, params = @params := params
WHERE guid = 0 LIMIT 1;
```

It will return 1 or 0, depending on whether the values were effectively changed.

```
SELECT @params AS params;
```

This one just selects the variable from the connection.

From: [here](http://johnbokma.com/mexit/2012/03/15/job-queue-in-mysql.html)