# Insert and retrieve the old value (MySQL php)

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with columns: [id, value] (id = integer PK, value= integer). I'd like to update the value column for a given id, retrieveing the old value. Is posible to do this in a single query? or I need to make a query and then an insert?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Possible duplicate of (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass) Short answer is it can't really be done with a single query, but you can create procedure to do it, allowing a single query to accomplish the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a trigger that puts the old value in another table (or even into another column of the current table). Other than that, you'd need to do two queries.