# Stored Procedure: How can I return a selected row from a table and increment a column in the selected table row

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, select

How can I select a row from a table and increment a column in the selected row while still returning the full selected row for further processing in PHP.

I'd like to output the results of a select statement, for example...

SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE something='else';

This table would have a unique 'id' column.

During the same procedure I'd like to increment a column of the selected table row.

Is this possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe you can do this in a single SQL statement. You can do it with a stored procedure, similar to what is described in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass). Would you want the column value before or after the increment?

Comment: The incremented value doesn't matter as far as the returned data, so it could be before or after. But I'd want multiple column values from the row returned. Thanks.

Comment: Are there any benefits to doing that instead of something similar to ...
SET @id = 0; SELECT (@id := id) AS id, tbl.another FROM tbl WHERE something='else';
UPDATE tbl SET num = num + 1 WHERE id = @id;

Comment: @christian - One advantage is that calling a stored procedure is a single interaction with the server. A stored procedure can also incorporate locking and/or transaction processing to improve data integrity. The down side to a stored procedure is that it is a bit more load on the server and (perhaps for that reason alone) some ISPs disable stored procedures for MySQL.