# Select Statement With An Update

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating a site that displays articles. The article table has the following fields:

```
article_id
title
text
views
```

ATM I am selecting the the article and outputting it but I would like to also **increment the views in the same query** ie "views=views+1".

The query would look like this

```
SELECT article_id, title, text, views
SET views=views+1
WHERE article_id=:article_id
```

I want to get the incremented result of views as well in the output so I am guessing I would need place the SET before the SELECT.

Comment: i think you will have to use 2 queries

Comment: I guess you cant do this in one query.

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would have to be two separate queries.

```
SELECT 
    article_id, 
    title, 
    text, 
    views
FROM TABLE
WHERE article_id = article_id;

UPDATE TABLE
SET views = views + 1
WHERE article_id = article_id;
```

You could wrap those in a transaction to force both to either happen or rollback.

```
START TRANSACTION;

SELECT 
    article_id, 
    title, 
    text, 
    views
FROM TABLE
WHERE article_id = article_id;

UPDATE TABLE
SET views = views + 1
WHERE article_id = article_id;

COMMIT;
```