# MYSQL SELECT and INCREMENT in SAME QUERY?

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to keep track how many times a row was returned in a mysql query. Is there a way to INCREMENT row data as it is selected? I would like to do this in one shot vs running two queries.

So a rough idea,

```
SELECT * FROM data WHERE text in($search) & UPDATE hits=hits+1
```

Something like that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/562693/mysql-update-and-select-in-one-pass

Comment: @user20232359723568423357842364: all of those answers are terrible... But then again, so is the query. :)

Comment: I think you're SOL on MySQL.  PostgreSQL will let you do an UPDATE... RETURNING but other than that it will likely need to be handled in your application tier.

Comment: It's worth reading up on triggers for things like this as well.

Comment: @JerrySeeger: MySQL can't fire triggers on `SELECT`.

Comment: @eggyal By gum, you're right. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

> SELECT * FROM data WHERE text in($search) & UPDATE hits=hits+1

Assuming `hits` is in `data`, you can do this in two queries like so:

```
UPDATE data
SET hits=hits+1
WHERE text in($search);

SELECT * FROM data WHERE text in($search);
```

Postgres would allow you to do it in a single statement with a `returning *` clause on the `update` statement, but that's about it.

Comment: I'd further add that the above can be conducted atomically using transactions.